# Trying to set up Orleans Cluster membership with Consul

Tags: consul, orleans

I'm trying to use an existing Consul cluster as the membership provider for a test Orleans application.

I get this error when connecting my client app to the Silo

> Could not find any gateway in Orleans.Runtime.Host.ConsulBasedMembershipTable. Orleans client cannot initialize.

Digging into the ConsulUtils class, the entries being retrieved have no ProxyPort defined - and are discarded - hence the empty result set.

I initialize the silo like this:

```
        var clusterConfiguration = new ClusterConfiguration();
        clusterConfiguration.Globals.DataConnectionString = "http://localhost:8500";
        clusterConfiguration.Globals.DeploymentId = "OrleansPlayground";
        clusterConfiguration.Globals.LivenessType = GlobalConfiguration.LivenessProviderType.Custom;
        clusterConfiguration.Globals.MembershipTableAssembly = "OrleansConsulUtils";
        clusterConfiguration.Globals.ReminderServiceType = GlobalConfiguration.ReminderServiceProviderType.Disabled;

        var silohost = new SiloHost("Fred", clusterConfiguration);

        silohost.InitializeOrleansSilo();
        startup = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return silohost.StartOrleansSilo();
        });
        return true;
```

And I set my client app up like this:

```
        var config = new ClientConfiguration();

        config.CustomGatewayProviderAssemblyName = "OrleansConsulUtils";
        config.DataConnectionString = "http://localhost:8500"; 
        config.DeploymentId = "OrleansPlayground";
        config.GatewayProvider = ClientConfiguration.GatewayProviderType.Custom;

        GrainClient.Initialize(config);
```

Looking at the code in ConsulUtils I can see that the ProxyPort isn't set (i.e. is 0) when the entry is saved.  So I'm assuming I have a problem when initializing the silo - but I can't figure out what it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging deep in, does sound like a bug. Please repost on GitHub and we will try to help you.

Comment: Thanks! I've added it as an issue - https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/2370